# Mobile web - hidden numerical input

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, mobile-website, mobilewebforms

Hi I am writing a web app (mainly iphone targeted) where the user has to enter their dob as part of the log in, I need this to be  `<input type = 'password'`however I also want to enable the numeric section of the keyboard. I would usually change the type attr to 'number' however as this needs to be hidden I wondered if there was another way to activate the numeric pad

Cheers!

(ps I do not want to use any frameworks such as jquery on this)

Comment: This makes no sense. You can't have an input `type=hidden` and be able  to enter something at the same time. Why does the type *have* to be hidden? Why can't you use type `number`?

Comment: Sorry I meant `type="password"`

Comment: Any proper mobile keyboard always allows access to numbers.

Comment: using the numberpad isnt the problem, I want it to default to it rather than user having to do the work

Answer (score 2):

I know this will probably not help the original poster (as I'm using my super necroposting powers) but here's how I've dealt with the problem (creating a field which has both password masking AND calls the numeric keyboard), for future generations' sake:

The answer is very simple:

1. First of all, fetch yourself a masking font (one that displays all characters as "●").
2. Create yourself a CSS font-face which uses that font.
3. Create an input with the "tel" type () and apply the font-face to it.

So basically, it is not really a password field, but a regular input field using a font that displays all characters as "●".

Here's a usable font for that matter:
[http://www.director-online.com/dougwiki/index.php?title=Password_Font_(ttf)](http://www.director-online.com/dougwiki/index.php?title=Password_Font_%28ttf%29)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard type is fired based on the input type. There's currently no other way to force the keyboard type to use.

Answer (score 0):

That makes much more sense :-)

I've found an (older) article an this, where the iPhone uses the numeric keyboard, if the name of the element contains: `zip` or `phone`:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1197-Defaulting-To-The-Numeric-Keyboard-On-The-iPhone.htm

I have no idea if that still works and if it's true for password fields, but try naming your field `"birthday_zip"`, or something similar, and see if it works.